# Open cover; why is the following open?

Tags: general-topology

I am asked to look at the following

> For $n=0,1,2...$ define $U_n \subseteq [0,1]$ by $U_0=[0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $U_n=(2^{-n},1]$ for $n \geq 1$.

So, along the unit interval, we have a cover from zero to half and other sets $U_n$ covering $1/2,1/4...$ to $1$. Here's a question I cannot answer

> Then $(U_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$. Why is this open?

No idea. Rather, aren't they..."clopen"? Clearly, each $U_n$ has one side "open" which is "(" or ")" but the other end is always "closed" "[ or ]."

Thus aren't each of $U_n$ ..clopen? So neither opened nor closed. So I am forced to challenge the statement above; they aren't open.

I checked the definition of open in this context but indeed,

> $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ is open if $U_i$ is open for each $i \in I$.

Well, immediately, for $i = 1$, $U_1=(\frac{1}{2},1]$ which is not open(nor closed) so I've found a counterexample.

Please tell me why I am wrong!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is indeed an open cover.

Saying a set is "open" (or "closed," or . . .) only makes sense in the context of a topological space. Sets which are open in one topological space may not be open in another, etc.

In this case, the space we're living in is $[0, 1]$. Well, that's the underlying *set*, anyways - what's the topology on it? It's the *subspace topology* coming from the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. A set $V\subseteq [0, 1]$ is open *in this sense* if $V=[0, 1]\cap U$ for some $U$ which is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (in the usual sense).

So actually, sets like $({1\over 2}, 1]$ **are open** (in this space)! For instance, $({1\over 2}, 1]=({1\over 2}, 17)\cap [0, 1]$.

---

Moral: always check the space we're living in!

Comment: I'm going to have to quibble with this.  The question of what space and what topology we have is never stated.  We have no effin' clue whether the sets are open, closed, clopen, neither, both.  I'm willing to assume we are in the euclidean metric space on the Reals without being told so, but I am not willing to assume we are in the space [0,1].... *unless* the section of the book describing covers is assuming covers of *spaces*; not subsets.  I *will* grant that these are all subsets of easy to find open sets so every relevent worry of open covers is insignificant.

Comment: Man, I keep imagining opens and closes in metrics....i'm struggling so much to build on intuition like you who can naturally think about what space we're talking about and why and how some things are therefore...thanks for the help

Comment: @fleablood I mean, it seems pretty clear to from the question that this is the space we're living in. I grant that that's an assumption on my part, but I strongly suspect it's a correct one (as evidenced by the fact that the OP accepted my answer).

Comment: Oh, I agree it's pretty clear it's meant to be  in the space [0,1].  Otherwise the covers wouldn't be open and they would be "sheared" at the end points.  But I have to quibble that it really needs to be stated.

Comment: John Trail.  I admit that it can get counter intuitive.  But this isn't that counter intuitive if you keep in mind spaces "exist within themselves".  0 and 1 are end points but they are endpoints "at the end of the universe".  Something is open intuitively  if it doesn't have clear edge points beyond which you leave the set.  0 and 1 don't count because even though they are sharp edges, they aren't sharp edges you can go beyond.

Answer (score 2):

They are open in the subspace topology of $[0,1]$

For example, in your example $U_1 = (\dfrac{1}{2}, 1]$ is open, because it is an intersection of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ say $(\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{3}{2})$ with $[0,1]$